# VBA Selenium Date Selector in iframe

Tags: vba, selenium

[image]

[image]

I am trying to select a date but currently struggling. This date selector is in a iframe. I have switched to iframe but no nothing works to select the date, I have trying to change the data in this value part but it still does not work. I used the CSS, Xpath, ID, Class but nothing works.

.

I have found that using the Xpath is work for all the other elements like selecting time and dropdown.

With obj
'open edge
.Start "edge"
End With

```
    'declare URL
    Dim url As String
    url = "http://cogprodweb.co.za"
    
    'nagivate to url
    obj.Get (url)
    

    
      With obj
        'Wait for frame to load and then Select the iframe
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
         .SwitchToFrame ("iC93CD3A10B5343779D27E431CE7AF966")
         
         'Select Locations
         .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/form[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/select/option[9]", 3000).click

         'Select Date
         .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/form[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input", 3000).SendKeys("2021-07-19").click
```

I through identifying the calendar (which is table) and them running from the cells until it equal to inputted value (yesterday).  I am not sure what do you for that. The variables, I have been looking at has not been working out. Looking at this to.

[Iterating Through Table Rows in Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090653/iterating-through-table-rows-in-selenium-python/55390258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the id of the iframe is being regenerated and the locator you're using might be no good i.e:
.SwitchToFrame ("iC93CD3A10B5343779D27E431CE7AF966")

either use a solid locator (add an id to the iframe element in html) or use a different locator meanwhile.

you can debug this and try to grab the iframe element with the id that was generated and see if indeed it's the locator issue or not